# Install qgis on ubuntu bionic

Tags: apt, 18.04

I am trying to install the latest version of `qgis=3.10` on a `ubuntu18.04` server. I have been following several online tutorial/post but without success.

Here some information:

1) The end of my `/etc/apt/sources.list`

```
deb https://qgis.org/ubuntu bionic main
```

2) `apt-get update` run succesfully

When trying to run `sudo apt-get install qgis` I get:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 qgis : Depends: gdal-abi-2-2-3
    Depends: libqgis-analysis3.10.0 but it is not going to be installed
    Depends: libqgis-app3.10.0 but it is not going to be installed
    Depends: libqgis-core3.10.0 but it is not going to be installed
    Depends: libqgis-gui3.10.0 but it is not going to be installed
    Depends: python3-qgis (= 1:3.10.0+28bionic) but it is not going to be installed
    Depends: qgis-providers (= 1:3.10.0+28bionic) but it is not going to be installed
    Recommends: qgis-plugin-grass but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Can somebody help me out here?

EDIT1

Running `apt-cache policy` the only qgis-related entry is:

```
 500 https://qgis.org/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
 release o=QGIS project,a=bionic,n=bionic,l=QGIS   repository,c=main,b=amd64
 origin qgis.org
```

EDIT2

`grep -r ^deb /etc/apt/ --include="*.list"` :

```
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/developer_download_nvidia_com_compute_machine_learning_repos_ubuntu1804_x86_64.list:deb http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning   /repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64 /
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/developer_download_nvidia_com_compute_cuda_repos_ubuntu1804_x86_64.list:deb [trusted=yes] http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos   /ubuntu1804/x86_64 /
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb https://qgis.org/ubuntu bionic main
```

`apt-cache policy qgis qgis-providers qgis-plugin-grass libgdal20` :

```
qgis:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:3.10.0+28bionic
  Version table:
 1:3.10.0+28bionic 500
    500 https://qgis.org/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
 2.18.17+dfsg-1 500
    500 http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
qgis-providers:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:3.10.0+28bionic
  Version table:
 1:3.10.0+28bionic 500
    500 https://qgis.org/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
 2.18.17+dfsg-1 500
    500 http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
qgis-plugin-grass:
 Installed: (none)
 Candidate: 1:3.10.0+28bionic
 Version table:
 1:3.10.0+28bionic 500
    500 https://qgis.org/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
 2.18.17+dfsg-1 500
    500 http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
libgdal20:
 Installed: 2.4.0+dfsg-1~bionic0
 Candidate: 2.4.0+dfsg-1~bionic0
 Version table:
*** 2.4.0+dfsg-1~bionic0 100
    100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
 2.2.3+dfsg-2 500
    500 http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
```

Comment: maybe you have some other conflicting repo ?

Comment: pLumo see the edit

Comment: might be true for package `qgis`, but it may affect some dependecy of a dependency of `qgis` ...

Comment: Where should I start to investigate and potentially solve those conflict?

Comment: Can't reproduce on clean 18.04 LTS VM. Please add output of `grep -r ^deb /etc/apt/ --include="*.list"` and `apt-cache policy qgis qgis-providers qgis-plugin-grass libgdal20` to the question.

Comment: @N0rbert Please see the EDIT2. Thanks for the help

Comment: For me it seems that you simply force installation of older version of libgdal20 - with `sudo apt install libgdal20=2.2.3+dfsg-2` and then proceed with QGIS installation.

Comment: @N0rber Isn't libgdal2. 4.0+dfsg the one installed? Are u suggesting to remove libgdal2. 4 and install 2.3 or the other way around? Thanks

Comment: I suppose that this library was installed as local deb. Please install version from the regular repository and check will it fix the QGIS issue or not :)

Answer (score 0):

According to [ubuntugis documentation](https://trac.osgeo.org/ubuntugis/wiki/UbuntuGISRepository). "A convenient new command is available for adding Launchpad PPA (Personal Package Archive) repositories via the command line: add-apt-repository."

For the stable PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ppa
```

Add this PPA and **remove** from /etc/apt/sources.list the sentences:

```
deb https://qgis.org/ubuntugis/ bionic main
deb-src https://qgis.org/ubuntugis/ bionic main
```

After that install QGIS:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install qgis python3-qgis qgis-plugin-grass
```

## In case of key errors you can follow this instructions according to [qgis](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html#debian-ubuntu).

Add the qgis.org repository public key:

```
wget -O - https://qgis.org/downloads/qgis-2019.gpg.key | gpg --import
gpg --fingerprint 51F523511C7028C3

gpg --export --armor 51F523511C7028C3 | sudo apt-key add -
```

This work for me. If you're in the same issue you should try this.